MapBoxSDK を利用して Android かつ Offline 環境で地図を表示したい
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/maps/testapp/examples/OfflineActivity.kt
上記のサイトを見ながら Android 用の MapBoxSDK を利用してオフライン環境で地図を表示させようとしています。
しかし、以下の部分の TILE_REGION_ID、STYLE_PACK_METADATA、TILE_REGION_METADATA の意味が分からず、具体的にどのような値を入れればよいか分かりません。
この部分の意味やどのような文脈で使用されるか、具体的にどのような値をセットすべきか、どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。
  companion object {
    private const val TAG = "OfflineActivity"
    private const val ZOOM = 12.0
    private val TOKYO: Point = Point.fromLngLat(139.769305, 35.682027)
    private const val TILE_REGION_ID = "myTileRegion"
    private const val STYLE_PACK_METADATA = "my-outdoor-style-pack"
    private const val TILE_REGION_METADATA = "my-outdoors-tile-region"
  }

